# select Only first column checkbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to select first column of simple table. 
here is my code but it select all checkbox appear in table. how to avoid it.

**Html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" width="
300">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">select all!</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/> </td>
        <td>test!</td>
        <td>hi!</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/> </td>
        <td>test!</td>
        <td>hi!</td>
    </tr>



     <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/> </td>
        <td>test!</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>


    $('#selectAll').click(function(e){
        var table= $(e.target).closest('table');
        $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
    </script>
```

**Expected Output**

[image: output]

Here all checkbox selected in table but i want to select only first column checkbox in table. please suggest me better way

Comment: Don't duplicate ids, uses classes instead !

Comment: You can't begin and id with a number, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the checkbox selector to only select the checkboxes from the first `td` in a row: `td:first-child`.

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function(e) {
  var table = $(e.target).closest('table');
  $('td:first-child input:checkbox', table).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" width="
300">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
    </th>
    <th colspan="2">select all!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1" /> </td>
    <td>test!</td>
    <td>hi!</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1" /> </td>
    <td>test!</td>
    <td>hi!</td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1" /> </td>
    <td>test!</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply change on first td of every row.

Here is working code

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function(e){
        $(e.target).closest('table').find("tr td:first-child input:checkbox").prop('checked',this.checked)
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="
300" >
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
    </th>
    <th colspan="2">select all!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" /> </td>
    <td>test!</td>
    <td>hi!</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" /> </td>
    <td>test!</td>
    <td>hi!</td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" /> </td>
    <td>test!</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below. It selects first td under each tr and then selects checkbox under it.

```
 $('tr td:first-child input[type=checkbox]',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use td:first-child

```js
  $('#selectAll').click(function(e){
        var table= $(e.target).closest('table');
      table.find('td:first-child input:checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="300">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">select all!</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="firstRow"/> </td>
        <td>test!</td>
        <td>hi!</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="firstRow"/> </td>
        <td>test!</td>
        <td>hi!</td>
    </tr>



     <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="firstRow"/> </td>
        <td>test!</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```